# Only login page is not being displayed in required 1080p resolution(ubuntu 14 lts)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution

After fresh Ubuntu 14 fresh installation ,I installed proprietary nvidia graphics driver then generated xorg.conf file by using nvidia-xconfig .Changed the Vsynch and HSynch values to get 1080p.I get this resolution only after i login to my account i.e login page is being displayed in 640 resolution.
    Is there anyway i could make the login page to be displayed in 1080p resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity.
```

You need to type these commands in terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) or Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: how will this help man??,sry for the late reply